# slideshow of images using jquery from the right center of the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I am working on making slideshow of images and I was trying to use this tutorial: http://www.slidesjs.com/

I downloaded the zip file and started using it and it works fine. Only thing I was trying out but couldn't make it work was those four dots at the right bottom, I wanted them to be on the actual image but at right center just on the border line.

An example will be like this: https://s2.postimg.org/ochp3uevt/scroller.png

if you check above image out (not showing full image), in this all the dots are vertical instead of horizontal and at the right center on that image. I want to do something similar as well. Is this possible to do that?

I tried using `margin-top` but it didn't worked for me.

**Update:-**

There is a CSS from which that four dots image is coming up and I have modified that to include margin-top but it didn't worked:

```
.slidesjs-pagination li a {
  display: block;
  width: 13px;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 13px;
  background-image: url("https://s16.postimg.org/pt4k43i9x/pagination.png");
  background-position: 0 0;
  float: left;
  <!-- added by me-->
  margin-top: -50px; 
}
```

Here is the full HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SlidesJS Standard Code Example</title>
  <meta name="description" content="SlidesJS is a simple slideshow plugin for jQuery. Packed with a useful set of features to help novice and advanced developers alike create elegant and user-friendly slideshows.">
  <meta name="author" content="Nathan Searles">

  <!-- SlidesJS Required (if responsive): Sets the page width to the device width. -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

  <!-- CSS for slidesjs.com example -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/example.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- End CSS for slidesjs.com example -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Optional: If you'd like to use this design -->
  <style>
    body {
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      font: normal 15px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      color: #232525;
      padding-top:70px;
    }

    #slides,
    #slides2,
    #slides3 {
      display: none;
      margin-bottom:50px;
    }

    .slidesjs-navigation {
      margin-top:3px;
    }

    .slidesjs-previous {
      margin-right: 5px;
      float: left;
    }

    .slidesjs-next {
      margin-right: 5px;
      float: left;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination {
      margin: 6px 0 0;
      float: right;
      list-style: none;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li {
      float: left;
      margin: 0 1px;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li a {
      display: block;
      width: 13px;
      height: 0;
      padding-top: 13px;
      background-image: url("https://s16.postimg.org/pt4k43i9x/pagination.png");
      background-position: 0 0;
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li a.active,
    .slidesjs-pagination li a:hover.active {
      background-position: 0 -13px
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li a:hover {
      background-position: 0 -26px
    }

    a:link,
    a:visited {
      color: #333
    }

    a:hover,
    a:active {
      color: #9e2020
    }

    .navbar {
      overflow: hidden
    }
  </style>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Optional-->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: These styles are required if you'd like a responsive slideshow -->
  <style>
    #slides {
      display: none
    }

    .container {
      margin: 0 auto
    }

    /* For tablets & smart phones */
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      body {
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
      }
      .container {
        width: auto
      }
    }

    /* For smartphones */
    @media (max-width: 480px) {
      .container {
        width: auto
      }
    }

    /* For smaller displays like laptops */
    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
      .container {
        width: 724px
      }
    }

    /* For larger displays */
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
      .container {
        width: 1170px
      }
    }
  </style>
  <!-- SlidesJS Required: -->
</head>
<body>
  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Start Slides -->
  <!-- The container is used to define the width of the slideshow -->
  <div class="container">
    <div id="slides">
      <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/7cyxxftpd/example-slide-1.jpg" alt="Photo by: Missy S Link: http://www.flickr.com/photos/listenmissy/5087404401/">
      <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/5mfwvyc69/example-slide-2.jpg" alt="Photo by: Daniel Parks Link: http://www.flickr.com/photos/parksdh/5227623068/">
      <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/48oa0ncwx/example-slide-3.jpg" alt="Photo by: Mike Ranweiler Link: http://www.flickr.com/photos/27874907@N04/4833059991/">
      <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/rbjedk3s1/example-slide-4.jpg" alt="Photo by: Stuart SeegerLink: http://www.flickr.com/photos/stuseeger/97577796/">
      <a href="#" class="slidesjs-previous slidesjs-navigation"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="slidesjs-next slidesjs-navigation"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required: Start Slides -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Link to jQuery -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Link to jquery.slides.js -->
  <script src="js/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Initialize SlidesJS with a jQuery doc ready -->
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#slides').slidesjs({
        width: 940,
        height: 528,
        navigation: false
      });

      /*
        To have multiple slideshows on the same page
        they just need to have separate IDs
      */
      $('#slides2').slidesjs({
        width: 940,
        height: 528,
        navigation: false,
        start: 3,
        play: {
          auto: true
        }
      });

      $('#slides3').slidesjs({
        width: 940,
        height: 528,
        navigation: false
      });
    });
  </script>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should be, post the code you're working with currently and what you've tried.

Comment: I updated the css code which I was working with and modified it as well.

Comment: Well, to position it relative to the main layout requires us seeing (with code) the rest of your layout. Can you provide the html, css and JS (preferebly as a snippet in your post) that reproduces the context of the layout you're working with?

Comment: I tried making jsfiddle out of it but somehow I am not able to make that work so instead update with the code. In this html code only I have to make changes in that css I believe which I have already tried but I failed.

Comment: what do you mean 'at the right center just on the border line'? I can't tell what you mean from the screenshot.

Comment: is this where you want it? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XgJWad

Comment: yes exactly but it is very close to right border may be little bit before the border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to absolutely position the menu to the right side with a value for `right` that will create space between the menu and the right side, move it to the center, then un-`float` the `li`'s.

```css
#slides {
  position: relative;
}
#slides .slidesjs-pagination {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; right: 1em;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 9999;
}
#slides .slidesjs-pagination li {
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slidesjs/3.0/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SlidesJS Standard Code Example</title>
  <meta name="description" content="SlidesJS is a simple slideshow plugin for jQuery. Packed with a useful set of features to help novice and advanced developers alike create elegant and user-friendly slideshows.">
  <meta name="author" content="Nathan Searles">

  <!-- SlidesJS Required (if responsive): Sets the page width to the device width. -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

  <!-- CSS for slidesjs.com example -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/example.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- End CSS for slidesjs.com example -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Optional: If you'd like to use this design -->
  <style>
    body {
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      font: normal 15px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      color: #232525;
      padding-top:70px;
    }

    #slides,
    #slides2,
    #slides3 {
      display: none;
      margin-bottom:50px;
    }

    .slidesjs-navigation {
      margin-top:3px;
    }

    .slidesjs-previous {
      margin-right: 5px;
      float: left;
    }

    .slidesjs-next {
      margin-right: 5px;
      float: left;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination {
      margin: 6px 0 0;
      float: right;
      list-style: none;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li {
      float: left;
      margin: 0 1px;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li a {
      display: block;
      width: 13px;
      height: 0;
      padding-top: 13px;
      background-image: url("https://s16.postimg.org/pt4k43i9x/pagination.png");
      background-position: 0 0;
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li a.active,
    .slidesjs-pagination li a:hover.active {
      background-position: 0 -13px
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li a:hover {
      background-position: 0 -26px
    }

    a:link,
    a:visited {
      color: #333
    }

    a:hover,
    a:active {
      color: #9e2020
    }

    .navbar {
      overflow: hidden
    }
  </style>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Optional-->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: These styles are required if you'd like a responsive slideshow -->
  <style>
    #slides {
      display: none
    }

    .container {
      margin: 0 auto
    }

    /* For tablets & smart phones */
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      body {
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
      }
      .container {
        width: auto
      }
    }

    /* For smartphones */
    @media (max-width: 480px) {
      .container {
        width: auto
      }
    }

    /* For smaller displays like laptops */
    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
      .container {
        width: 724px
      }
    }

    /* For larger displays */
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
      .container {
        width: 1170px
      }
    }
  </style>
  <!-- SlidesJS Required: -->
</head>
<body>
  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Start Slides -->
  <!-- The container is used to define the width of the slideshow -->
  <div class="container">
    <div id="slides">
      <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/7cyxxftpd/example-slide-1.jpg" alt="Photo by: Missy S Link: http://www.flickr.com/photos/listenmissy/5087404401/">
      <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/5mfwvyc69/example-slide-2.jpg" alt="Photo by: Daniel Parks Link: http://www.flickr.com/photos/parksdh/5227623068/">
      <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/48oa0ncwx/example-slide-3.jpg" alt="Photo by: Mike Ranweiler Link: http://www.flickr.com/photos/27874907@N04/4833059991/">
      <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/rbjedk3s1/example-slide-4.jpg" alt="Photo by: Stuart SeegerLink: http://www.flickr.com/photos/stuseeger/97577796/">
      <a href="#" class="slidesjs-previous slidesjs-navigation"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="slidesjs-next slidesjs-navigation"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required: Start Slides -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Link to jQuery -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Link to jquery.slides.js -->
  <script src="js/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Initialize SlidesJS with a jQuery doc ready -->
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#slides').slidesjs({
        width: 940,
        height: 528,
        navigation: false
      });

      /*
        To have multiple slideshows on the same page
        they just need to have separate IDs
      */
      $('#slides2').slidesjs({
        width: 940,
        height: 528,
        navigation: false,
        start: 3,
        play: {
          auto: true
        }
      });

      $('#slides3').slidesjs({
        width: 940,
        height: 528,
        navigation: false
      });
    });
  </script>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS by replacing the rules:

```
#slides {
    position: relative;
}
.slidesjs-pagination {
    margin: 6px 0 0;
    float: none;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 30px;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.slidesjs-pagination li {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 1px;
}

.slidesjs-pagination li a {
    display: block;
    width: 13px;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 13px;
    background-image: url(https://s16.postimg.org/pt4k43i9x/pagination.png);
    background-position: 0 0;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 5px 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by replacing the rules?

Comment: I mean you need to replace the css code blocks like .slidesjs-pagination li a { }